# Images are not loaded in mobile application built with cordova

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I have an angular application that works fine, from which I build a mobile application with apache cordova. The mobile application works fine, except that the images are not loaded because the path is not found.

Here is my file structure:

```
    angular.json
    package.json
    config.xml
    src
        assets
        index.html
    www
        assets
        index.html
```

Here is a part of angular.json:

```
    "outputPath": "www",
    "baseHref": "",
    "deployUrl": "",
    "index": "src/index.html",
    "main": "src/main.ts",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "aot": true,
    "assets": [
      "src/assets"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "src/assets/css/AdminLTE.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "src/assets/adminlte.min.js"
      "src/assets/bootstrap.min.js"
    ]
```

I also have changed the `<base href>` tag from "/" to "./". in index.html

Here are the commands I use:

```
    ng build --aot --prod
    cordova run android --device
    or
    cordova serve 1234
```

The problem comes both when running on my mobile device and when testing on the browser with cordova serve.

Here is the output of my development console:

`GET http://localhost:1234/android/www/index.html/scada/assets/spot.png 404 (Not Found)`

'scada' is the current URL path as defined in app.routing.ts. This means that the actual URL at this moment is:

```
http://localhost:1234/scada
```

The strange thing is that every other thing is working. Even the scripts are loaded perfectly.

Can someone tell what's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try defined the src in your images like `[src]="/assets/spot.png"` -see the `/` initial

Comment: Thanks Eliseo. That worked when running on browser with ```cordova serve PORT```.  However, it doesn't work when I run on device with ```cordova run android --device```. Images are not loaded. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, for anyone who is interested, here is the answer after a lot of debugging and digging:

On the opposite to most people state, the path that should be defined in the `<img` tag is NOT relative to the root path but is relative to the current URL. Example:

I have a controller (e.g. an angular component) which is loaded in the URL:

`http://myserver:PORT/path1/path2/path3`

The controller template (e.g. myController.component.html) has an `<img`  tag in order to load a picture from `src/assets/pictures/myPicture.png`.

Then, the `<img` tag should be defined as follows:
`<img src="../../../assets/pictures/myPicture.png`

As a note, adding `/` in front of the path does work on chrome but doesn't work on device.

BTW, `chrome://inspect` is a great tool for debbuging cordova apps running on device.